# Create a NSPredicate to find elements whose length is > N

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an array of strings ( more that 5k elements), each of variable length. I can use NSPredicate to find specific strings within the array( took a bit to figure that out). Now I need to find elements whose length is > than N.

I have looked through the documentation and Length does not seem to be one of the functions available in the Predicate Programming Guide.

Thanks in advance.

Imagmast

Comment: why was this down-voted?  i think it's good manners to explain your down-vote with a comment.  i'm guessing it's because the question didn't post code attempts?  a more constructive response (esp with a relatively low experience score) would be to ask him to post his string matching code.  +1 from me unless someone provides a good reason for the -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray * words= [allLinedStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > %d",N]];
```

N is your integer as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could you share links to other predicate "functions"?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with NSPredicate, so I can't give you a solution using it, but couldn't you just use some plain NSString methods:

```
//This is the length of the string you want to check
int threshold = 5;

//Iterates through all elements in the array
for(int index = 0; index < [stringArray count]; index++) {

    //Checks if the length of the string stored at the current index is greater than N
    if([[stringArray objectAtIndex:index] length] > threshold) {

        //String length is greater than N
    }
}
```

Optionally, you could add in a check to see if the array only has strings (sacrifices performance for safety) by replacing this line:

```
if([[stringArray objectAtIndex:index] length] > threshold)
```

With this:

```
if([[stringArray objectAtIndex:index] length] > threshold && [[stringArray objectAtIndex:index] isKindOfClass[NSString class]])
```

What this does is it makes sure that the object at the current index is an NSString. If it's not, you'd receive a runtime error.

Comment: Check the class before calling `length`.